# margin bottom property doesn't show empty space

Tags: html, css

In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXPBaG), I have tried to place the inner box in the center of outer box. As a hack, I used `margin-bottom: 20px;`.

But this property has no effect as I see zero space between the `inner` div's bottom line and `outer` div's border.

**Code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.content {
  width: 770px;
  margin: auto;
}
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  
  padding: 5%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="outer">
  Outer div
  <div class="inner">
    Inner div 1
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give `padding-bottom` to `.outer` instead and to center you set `width:auto` in `.inner`, check `snippet`.

#### Snippet (responsive and .inner centered)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.content {
  max-width: 770px;
  margin: auto;
}
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-bottom:20px
}
.inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center; 
  margin:auto;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="outer">
    Outer div
    <div class="inner">
      Inner div 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```